# Modify JSON response of Flask-Restless

Tags: python, ember.js, flask, flask-restless

I am trying to use Flask-Restless with Ember.js which isn't going so great. It's the GET responses that are tripping me up. For instance, when I do a `GET` request on `/api/people` for example Ember.js expects:

```
{ 
    people: [
        { id: 1, name: "Yehuda Katz" }
    ] 
}
```

But Flask-Restless responds with:

```
{
    "total_pages": 1, 
    "objects": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Yahuda Katz" }
    ], 
    "num_results": 1, 
    "page": 1
}
```

How do I change Flask-Restless's response to conform to what Ember.js would like? I have this feeling it might be in a postprocessor function, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Sigh... I tried asking the inverse question and somebody just said I should change how Flask-Restless responds. TBH I am much more comfortable in Python so doing it this way does appeal to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer was correct at the time. However the post and preprocessors work in Flask-Restless have changed. [According to the documentation](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors):

> The preprocessors and postprocessors for each type of request accept
>   different arguments, but none of them has a return value (more
>   specifically, any returned value is ignored). Preprocessors and
>   postprocessors modify their arguments in-place.

So now in my postprocessor I just delete any keys that I do not want. For example:

```
def api_post_get_many(result=None, **kw):
    for key in result.keys():
        if key != 'objects':
            del result[key]
```

Answer (score 10):

Flask extensions have [pretty readable source code](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/master/flask_restless/views.py#L843). You can make a `GET_MANY` postprocessor:

```
def pagination_remover(results):
    return {'people': results['objects']} if 'page' in results else results

manager.create_api(
    ...,
    postprocessors={
        'GET_MANY': [pagination_remover]
    }
)
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: I am really embarrassed it was that simple, but thank you so much.

Comment: I tested this and it did not.

Comment: @datasmid: That's not helpful at all.